# How to sort using $\texttt{SQRTSORT}$ as a subroutine which sorts $\sqrt{n}$ of consecutive elements?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, sorting

I am teaching myself algorithms with the [online lecture notes by Jeff Erickson](http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/notes/all-notes.pdf) and fails to solve the following problem (Problem 21 of Lecture 1).

> (a) Describe an algorithm that sorts an input array $A[1 \ldots n]$ by calling a subroutine $\texttt{SQRTSORT}(k)$, which sorts the subarray $A[k + 1 \ldots k + \sqrt{n}]$ in place, given an arbitrary integer $k$ between $0$ and $n - \sqrt{n}$. How many times does your algorithm call $\texttt{SQRTSORT}$ in the worst case?

*Note: To simplify the problem, assume that $\sqrt{n}$ is an integer. Your algorithm is **only** allowed to inspect or modify the input array by calling $\texttt{SQRTSORT}$; in particular, your algorithm must not directly compare, move, or copy array elements.*

> (b) Prove that your algorithm from part (a) is optimal up to constant factors. In other words, if $f(n)$ is the number of times your algorithm calls $\texttt{SQRTSORT}$, prove that no algorithm can sort using $o(f(n))$ calls to $\texttt{SQRTSORT}$.

and,

> (c) Now suppose $\texttt{SQRTSORT}$ is implemented recursively, by calling your sorting algorithm from part (a). For example, at the second level of recursion, the algorithm is sorting arrays roughly of size $n^{\frac{1}{4}}$. What is the worst-case running time of the resulting sorting algorithm?

*Note: To simplify the analysis, assume that the array size $n$ has the form $2^{2^{k}}$, so that repeated square roots are always integers.*

---

**My Attempt:**

For part (a), I come up with a *probably* brute-force algorithm behaving like the $\texttt{BubbleSort}$, except that it treats $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$ of consecutive elements as a single one in $\texttt{BubbleSort}$. The number of calls of $\texttt{SQRTSORT}$ is at worst:

$$1 + 2 + \ldots + 2 \sqrt{n} = 2n + \sqrt{n} = \Theta(n)$$

For part (b), $\sqrt{n}$ is a trivial lower bound: Any reasonable algorithm must have done something on each element, consuming $\sqrt{n}$ calls of $\texttt{SQRTSORT}$.

---

**My Questions:**

> 1. How to show whether my solution is asymptotically optimal or not?
> 2. Do you have better algorithms with lower complexity, say, $\sqrt{n} \lg n$ or $n^{\frac{3}{4}}$. Actually, I am looking for the *optimal* one.

Comment: Here's a puzzle that might be related, which you might enjoy: Suppose I give you a subroutine that will sort any list of size $m$ in place.  How quickly can you sort a list of size $2m$, by repeatedly calling the subroutine?  How many invocations of the subroutine are necessary?  (It's possible to do it with $O(1)$ invocations of the subroutine.)

Comment: @D.W. It is possible to sort the list of size $2m$ by calling your subroutine 6 times, using the $\texttt{BubbleSort}$-like algorithm. `How many invocations of the subroutine are necessary?`: It is asking for the lower bound. I am not able to figure it out right now. However, consider the problem of sorting $2m = 4$ by `comparison` of any two ($m=2$) elements. It needs 5 `comparison`s at least. Back to my origin question, the size of the array to sort is $n = \sqrt{n} \times \sqrt{n}$ in which $\sqrt{n}$ is not a constant. I am stuck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for part (b): Consider the statistic $r(\pi) = \sum_i |i-\pi(i)|$. Running SQRTSORT can reduce $r(\pi)$ by at most $n$, while $r(n(n-1)\ldots1) = \Omega(n^2)$.

Hint for part (c): I get a running time of $O(n^2\log^{O(1)} n)$.

Comment: For part (c): I get $T(n) = n T(n^{1/2})$ which is $T(n) = \Theta(n^2)$. Could you please explain your method?

Comment: Sorry, corrected. You are missing a logarithmic term since it's really $T(n) = cnT(n^{1/2})$.

Comment: How does the constant $c$ become the logarithmic term $\log n$?

Comment: You tell me how.

Comment: Could you expalin more about your hint  for part (b)?